# Material Theme for IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 17

Tags: intellij-idea, material-design

I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Version 17.2 (build #IU-172-3575.52 built on August 15, 2017).
I want to install material theme on it (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui).

However, I am not able to find the right build for it. I managed to install version 1.6.1 of the theme which seemed to be be compatible to the installed version of my IntelliJ, but when I restarted the IDE, it gave an error and crashed.

I am on Windows 7.

Is there a compatible version of Material Theme for IntelliJ Ultimate 17.2?

Comment: Try 1.6.0.4 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui/update/42439

Comment: I don't see any option of installing/downloading the theme on the page..how do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but when searching how to install the Material Theme this thread was one of the top hits, so I just thought I would add the installation instructions here.

https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains#installation